# Destination of std::ctype::narrow() fills by default value

Tags: c++, stl, locale

I'm using `const CharT* narrow(const CharT* beg, const CharT* end, char dflt, char* dst) const` of a `std::ctype<wchar_t>` facet, but `dst` is filled by `dflt` value.

It's my code:

```
std::wstring str = L"ABC";
std::locale loc{ "en_US.utf8" };
const auto& fct = std::use_facet<std::ctype<wchar_t>>(loc);

std::string cstr;
cstr.resize(str.size());
fct.narrow(str.data(), str.data() + str.size(), '-', &cstr[0]);
std::cout << cstr << std::endl;
```

This is the output:

```
---
```

What's the reason?

Comment: Perhaps the "en_US.utf8" locale is not supported. In any case I think the simplest way to get an answer would be to debug your code and see what is actually happening in the standard library code you invoke.

Comment: Thank you. I changed `std::locale loc{ "en_US" };` and it`s work.

Answer (score 0):

Try to check the output from `std::has_facet`:

```
std::cout << "Has locale: " << std::has_facet<std::ctype<wchar_t>>(loc) << std::endl;
```

to check if the locale you are trying to use is supported.

Comment: `std::has_facet<std::ctype<wchar_t>>(loc)` for `std::locale loc{ "en_US.utf8" }` returns true, but `dst` stil fills by `dflt`. I changed locale to `std::locale loc{ "en_US" }` and it's works properly.